# Making su ask for password multiple times

Tags: password, authentication, su

Is there some way to make `su` ask for the password again in case of a wrong password (just as `sudo` does)?

Initially I thought of this:

```
while ! su -c foo; do
  read -n 1 -p "Retry(y/n)?" ch
  if [[ "$ch" != "y" ]]; then
    break
  fi
done
```

But `foo` returns 1 in some cases as well, making it impossible to detect whether a wrong password was entered or if `foo` failed.

Comment: Do you want to actually launch a root shell or just run a single command? If the latter, why not use `sudo` in the first place?

Comment: @terdon, some distros (like Slitaz) don't have `sudo` on them. (I don't have control over the boxes on which this script will be run).

Comment: Fair enough. So your aim is to run a specific command `foo` then? Not to keep the root shell open? In that case @psimon's answer should work for you.

Comment: Where does this script belong to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, I would suggest the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
while ! su -c "foo; exit 0"; do
    read -n 1 -p "Retry? (y/n) " ch
    [[ "$ch" != "y" ]] && break   # This does the same in fewer lines
done
```

This returns a zero value even if `foo` has a different exit code.
**WARNING:** using this workaround (which is a bit ugly), you won't be able to determine `foo`'s exit code. I don't know if it is required for your project.

Comment: I'm not sure if he wants a root shell after executing one command as root. I tried this script and it executes `foo` before exiting, so it won't "just exit".

Answer (score 0):

`su` returns 1 on an authentication failure, so arrange for the command to avoid this error code. For example, if you don't care about conflating status values 126 and 127:

```
while
  su -c 'foo; ret=$?; if [ "$ret" -ge 1 ] && [ "$ret" -le 126 ]; the ret=$((ret+1)); fi'
  ret=$?
  [ ret -ne 1 ]
do
  …
done
if [ "$ret" -ge 2 ] && [ "$ret" -le 126 ]; then ret=$((ret-1)); fi
echo "foo returned $ret" # or maybe 126 if this shows 127
```