# Make su ask for the password multiple times

Tags: su

I'm using Debian 8 and when I enter `su` the password prompt appears only once. If I enter the wrong password I expect retry and immediately start typing again but then parts of the password are visible on the shell.

How can I configure `su` to re-prompt for the password until I cancel it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

I tried looking in `/etc/sudoers`, `/etc/pam.d/*`, `/etc/login.defs` and this [unix.SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138256/making-su-ask-for-password-multiple-times) which is incomplete unfortunately.

Comment: Why is the other question's accepted answer not useful here? This does look like a duplicate to me

Comment: I don't know where those scripts belong to, besides I assume there is a built-in option.

Comment: Would a small maximum number of attempts (for example, three) be sufficient? If so I can give you a `pam`-based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PAM` modules can provide a level of flexibility that will achieve almost exactly what you want. Based on your response in a comment, you would be happy to allow `su` to offer three attempts before failing. That is what I offer here.

**I strongly recommend** that you backup every `PAM` configuration file that you change, and that you have a root shell already open somewhere ready to revert broken changes. After any change to `PAM` it is very important to test that you can still log in and gain root access. If you get it wrong you can completely hose your system.

The `PAM` files live in `/etc/pam.d`, and you will need root access to change them.

The `su` file on Debian 8 contains one authentication line and a reference to the include file `common-auth`. Putting them together we get this:

```
auth    sufficient pam_rootok.so

auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so

auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
```

The exciting part is the call to `pam_unix.so`, which authenticates against the password database (`/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`). The `[success=N]` component tells `PAM` that if the module returns a success status it is to skip the next N modules. So if you get a successful return from `pam_unix.so` the configuration will skip the failure module `pam_deny.so`.

We can use this approach to build a further two authentication attempts, like this:

```
auth    sufficient pam_rootok.so

auth    [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so

auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
```

There, job done.

---

Note, if you're running SAMBA or some other external authentication scheme you will need to adjust the changes slightly. On one of my systems there is such an additional check through `pam_winbind.so`. This would also need to be replicated, so you'd go from this:

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=FILE cached_login try_first_pass
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
```

to this:

```
auth    [success=6 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=5 default=ignore]      pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=FILE cached_login try_first_pass
auth    [success=4 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=FILE cached_login try_first_pass
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=FILE cached_login try_first_pass
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
```